# Feed the ref cursor in a loop

Tags: plsql

How to collect the output from stored procedure into a SYS_REFCURSOR,
in an orchestrating procedure like this, where getMusicanAvailability already exists
and returns the availability  based on inputs (Start, End) which should be collected in ref cursor.

```
Create Procedure Orchestra (
  Start         in  date;
  End           in  date;
  myList        out SYS_REFCURSOR

) as

available       varchar2(3);


begin
  for myMusican in
    select ID from Musicans
  loop
    -- Get the indivitual availability per a Musican
    getMusicanAvailability( myMusican.ID, Start, End, available );

    -- Here - how to do some 'push' the data into myList?
    ? myList.add( myMusican.ID, available );

  end loop;
end;
/
```

So if I call the Orchestra ( sydate, sysdate + 14 );
It will return the resultset, logically like this, because data were collected:

```
musican_X, YES
musican_Y, NO
musican_Z, NO
..
```

Or should I do it using the helper table, so instead of something like:

```
? myList.add( myMusican.ID, available )
```

I have to do:

```
insert into myListTable values ( myMusican.ID, available );
```

and then, to return it using Orchestra, it should be:

```
..
open myList for select * from myListTable;
return myList;

-- tidy up
delete from myListTable;
```

Comment: Would this example help you?: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php (Noticed this question, but I need to leave in 4 minutes, so just posting alink.)

Comment: You could either create a function that calls the procedure and returns the available value or convert the procedure into a function (which may or may not be possible) and then call that directly in a select statement. It probably won't be the fastest thing to do, however. The other alternative is to move the procedure logic directly into the SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, now I see (after deeper understanding what a cursor is).

Answer (score 0):

if `getMusicanAvailability` was a function that was callable from SQL (ie not out parameters and returned the string YES or NO) you could do it quite trivially with the following instead

```
Create or replace Procedure Orchestra (
  Start         in  date,
  End           in  date,
  myList        out SYS_REFCURSOR

) as
begin
  open myList   for
    select ID ,
           getMusicanAvailability( ID, Start, End) available
    from Musicans;
end;
/
```

but if you have already gone to that trouble you could just turn it into a straight view.

```
create or replace view Musican_availablility      
select ID ,
       getMusicanAvailability( ID, Start, End) available
from Musicans;
```

you could also wrap your procedure into a function to acheiv ethe same effect

```
Create or replace function getMusicanAvailability( 
   id NUMBER,
  Start         in  date,
  End           in  date) returns varchar2
is 
    available       varchar2(3);
begin
      getMusicanAvailability( myMusican.ID, Start, End, available );
    return available;
end;
```

and lastly a person who plays music is called a "musician" not a "musican" but I have left your spelling alone..